# SWT event propagation

Tags: java, events, swt, jface

I'm trying to detect click events on a Composite control that contains a number of other composites. I tried:

```
topComposite.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        ...
        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) {
            logger.info("HERE");
        });
});
```

But the event never fires. I assumed that when a mouse event occurred on a child it would propagate up the chain but that doesn't happen. How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In SWT, the general rule is that events *do not* propagate. The main exception to this, is the propagation of traverse events - which is pretty complicated to describe.

The easy answer to your problem is that you must add the listener to *all* the children of you `Composite` - *recursively*!

E.g. like this

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    // Create view...

    final MouseListener ma = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("down in " + e.widget);
        }
    };
    addMouseListener(parent, ma);
}

private void addMouseListener(Control c, MouseListener ma) {
    c.addMouseListener(ma);
    if (c instanceof Composite) {
        for (final Control cc : ((Composite) c).getChildren()) {
            addMouseListener(cc, ma);
        }
    }
}
```

The clicked-upon widget is found in `e.widget` as seen above. An important issue is to remember to do this again if you add more `Controls` later.

Comment: alternatively, if you do not want t add so many listeners - you can use a workaround. Capture ALL occured MouseEvents by `composite.getDisplay().addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {...}` and somehow pick the relevant events.

Comment: @Skip This is indeed possible as well, but be careful to deregister the listener again :-)